# Fallback Font Weights in CSS

Tags: css, fonts, sass, styles

My font stylesheets are hosted on Fonts.com and out of my control. On the stylesheet, different weights of Avenir are implemented as different font families, each with a weight of 400. If the weight is anything but the default `normal` (`400`), the font renders oddly. So how do I make my fallback fonts bold while keeping the primary font weight as normal?

---

I tried to accomplish this by using the `font` CSS shorthand, thinking I could define different weights for each comma-separated value, like so:

```
font:   normal 400 18px 'Avenir 85 Heavy',
        normal 800 18px 'Calbri',
        normal 800 18px sans-serif;
```

But the browser doesn't recognize this structure, unfortunately, unless I eliminate all properties besides `<font-family>` on the fallbacks. Any suggestions, even inelegant ones?

Answer (score 3):

When using `@font-face`, you typically want to apply a different font variant (= different font file), depending on whether your font is (1) `normal`, (2) `italic`, (3) `bold` or (4) `italic` + `bold`.

If you use **the same font-family** name for each variant along with their corresponding `font-style` and `font-weight` in your `@font-face` definitions, the correct font file will automatically be chosen depending on the `font-style` and `font-weight` of your elements.

Do this for all fonts defined with `@font-face`, and behavior should be as expected.

---

#### Demo

```css
@font-face {
  font-family : 'Droid Serif';
  font-style : normal;
  font-weight : 400;
  src: local('Droid Serif'),
       local('DroidSerif'),
       url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/droidserif/v6/0AKsP294HTD-nvJgucYTaI4P5ICox8Kq3LLUNMylGO4.woff2)
       format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family : 'Droid Serif';
  font-style : normal;
  font-weight : 700;
  src : local('Droid Serif Bold'),
        local('DroidSerif-Bold'),
        url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/droidserif/v6/QQt14e8dY39u-eYBZmppwYlIZu-HDpmDIZMigmsroc4.woff2)
        format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family : 'Droid Serif';
  font-style : italic;
  font-weight : 400;
  src : local('Droid Serif Italic'),
        local('DroidSerif-Italic'),
        url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/droidserif/v6/cj2hUnSRBhwmSPr9kS5898u2Q0OS-KeTAWjgkS85mDg.woff2)
        format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family : 'Droid Serif';
  font-style : italic;
  font-weight : 700;
  src : local('Droid Serif Bold Italic'),
        local('DroidSerif-BoldItalic'),
        url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/droidserif/v6/c92rD_x0V1LslSFt3-QEpo9ObOXPY1wUIXqKtDjSdsY.woff2)
        format('woff2');
}

body {
  font-family : "Droid Serif", Georgia, serif;
}

.bold, .both {
  font-weight : 700;
}

.italics, .both {
  font-style : italic;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph with <b>some bold text</b>, <em>some text in italics </em> and <em><b>some text that is both bold and in italics</b></em>!</p>
<p>Depending on whether your text is <span class="bold">bold</span >, <span class="italics">in italics</span > or <span class="both">both</span >, a different font will be used for the same font family!</p>
```